# React native Firebase Firestore query

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to display a user's order history using query. The users' orders, dubbed "items", is an array and I can see the array being logged in the console with my code below. But nothing is being displayed in the app. What am I missing? Also attached my Firestore db for reference.

[image: firestore db]

```
const q = query(ordersCollectionRef, where("items", "==", "userId"));
onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
let orders = [];
snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
  orders.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
});
console.log(orders);
});
```

...and in the return:

```
{orders.map((order) => {
        if (order.id === currentUser.uid) {
          return (
            <View>
              <Text>test{orders.items}</Text>
            </View>
          );
         };
      })}
```

Comment: `orders` needs to be a state variable. React doesn't rerender unless you set state.

Comment: Yup, I did: const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);

Comment: Ok, then do you ever call `setOrders`? That's not in the code you showed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For React to properly "understand" that you have updated data in a state variable, you need to use the "set state function" and NOT update the state variable directly.

In your code, put the data into a new and temporary variable, the after the `forEach()` call: `setOrders(theTempVariable)`

That puts the data in theTempVariable into the `orders` variable and it tells React that the variable has a new value....so React will "react" to state changing and it will re-render your component.